# Error 4198 on MSWord macro to open and Save As a folder of files

Tags: vba, ms-word

As part of a large-scale website review, I'll be scraping our website to save content to offline html documents. This part I've managed to automate nicely with a scraping tool and an Excel macro to clean up the results. I've got a small set of pages already exported this way, that I'm trying to get the next step working: Open each html file in Word, and then save it as a Word document (so that the SMEs and Editorial department can go back and forth with their ultimate goal of extensive re-writes).

Anyway, I'm 95% of the way there, and can get the pages exported into Word just fine, except that one document gets missed each time (whichever one is the "first" document in the fold, alphabetically), and the macro throws error 4198, "Command Failed", with no further hint as to what's missing.

Here's my macro, embedded in a .docm file that is saved in the parent folder (and only has plain text contents that are instructions on how to run the file in case I'm not the one using it in the future):

```
Sub HTMLtoDOCX()
    Dim StrFile As String
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Dim StrFilename As String
    Dim StrOldFilename As String
    Dim StrNewFilename As String
    Dim StrDir As String
        
    StrFile = Dir(ThisDocument.Path & "\Site Content\HTML\*.html")
    
    Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
        StrFile = Dir
        StrFilename = fso.GetBaseName(StrFile)
        StrOldFilename = StrFilename & ".html"
        StrNewFilename = StrFilename & ".docx"
        
        ChangeFileOpenDirectory _
        ThisDocument.Path & "\Site Content\HTML"
        
        Documents.Open FileName:=StrOldFilename, ConfirmConversions:= _
        False, ReadOnly:=False, AddToRecentFiles:=False, PasswordDocument:="", _
        PasswordTemplate:="", Revert:=False, WritePasswordDocument:="", _
        WritePasswordTemplate:="", Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto, XMLTransform:=""
                
        ChangeFileOpenDirectory _
        ThisDocument.Path & "\Site Content\DOCX"
        
        ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FileName:=StrNewFilename, _
        FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument, LockComments:=False, Password:="", _
        AddToRecentFiles:=True, WritePassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, _
        EmbedTrueTypeFonts:=False, SaveNativePictureFormat:=False, SaveFormsData _
        :=False, SaveAsAOCELetter:=False, CompatibilityMode:=15
        
        ActiveDocument.Close
        
    Loop
End Sub
```

If I have "../Site Content/HTML" with

- apples.html
- oranges.html
- pineapples.html
- zucchinis.html

then after I run the macro, the contents of "../Site Content/DOCX" will be

- oranges.docx
- pineapples.docx
- zucchinis.docx

If I delete all the files of DOCX, and rename apples.html to upples.html and run it again, then I end up with

- pineapples.docx
- upples.docx
- zucchinis.docx

So it's not the actual apples.html file that is the problem, it's the macro.

Comment: The first `Dir()` is before loop. `StrFile = Dir` in the loop skips the first html. Move the code `StrFile = Dir` above the `Loop`. Which line throws error 4198?

Comment: @taller moving `StrFile = Dir` before the loop causes it to repeatedly open and save the second file in the folder.


The highlighted part if I click on Debug is the `ActiveDocument.SaveAs2` statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    StrFile = Dir(ThisDocument.Path & "\Site Content\HTML\*.html")

Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
    StrFilename = fso.GetBaseName(StrFile)
    StrOldFilename = StrFilename & ".html"
    StrNewFilename = StrFilename & ".docx"
...        
    ActiveDocument.Close
    StrFile = Dir
    
Loop
```